# Pattern to add listener to method call? Is there an example?

Tags: android

I have been working with a ChannelClient and saw how you could call a method and add a listener to it. It does not exactly seem like the builder pattern but I was wondering to create my own class using the same technique. Is there an example? This seems like a great way to either add a listener or not.

```
 ChannelClient channelClient = Wearable.getChannelClient(getContext());
 channelClient.openChannel(node,path).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ChannelClient.Channel>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ChannelClient.Channel channel) {

      }
 });
```

So for my class:

```
public class TokenMessage {

      private String name;
      private int id;

      public TokenMessage(int id, String name) {
           this.id=id;
           this.name=name;
      }

      public void generateCode() {

      }

}
```

How do I add addOnSuccessListener to the method call. I assume I create a public interface in the class, but how do I add it to a method call? How do I add it to the generateCode method?

There are also addOnFailureListener and addOnCompleteListener methods which can be appended to the call as well.

**ADDITION**

I would want to be able to add multiple listeners and have the call to look like this:

```
TokenMessage tokenMessage = new TokenMessage(42,"Name");

tokenMessage.generate().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<int>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(int code) {

      }
 }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NotNull Exception e) {

      }
 });
```

Comment: are you talking about callbacks with an interface ?

Comment: Yes. I tried to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reverse engineer what your class will look like from the requirements:

Assuming you want something like this:

```
TokenMessage message = new TokenMessage(42, "Name");
message.addOnSuccessListener(new TokenMessage.OnSuccessListener() {
    void onSuccess() {
        doSuccessfulThings();
    }
}).addSomeOtherListener(...)
```

Then clearly you need:

1. A method to set a listener object that returns the same object for chaining.
2. Listener interfaces that you can set.
3. Variable to hold the interface instances in your object.
4. Calls to the callback methods on the interface objects based on logic of `generateCode`.

Then your code would look something like this:

```
public class TokenMessage {
  interface OnSuccessListener {
    void onSuccess();
  }

  // Other interfaces for failure etc

  private String name;
  private int id;

  private OnSuccessListener onSuccessListener;
  // Other member fields

  public TokenMessage(int id, String name) {
       this.id=id;
       this.name=name;
  }

  public TokenMessage generate() {
    launchTaskThatTakesALongTime();
    return this
  }

  // Setter that returns the object for chaining
  public TokenMessage addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener listener) {
    onSuccessListener = listener;
    return this;
  }

  private void launchTaskThatTakesALongTime() {
    // Use your preferred async / threading paradigm to run your task in the background. When they complete, invoke your listeners:
    // if (success && successListener != null) {
    //  successListener.onSuccess()
    //}
  }

  // Other setters for other callbacks 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. My question was not as clear as it should be. I am looking to create the same structure for a custom class, not use the ChannelClient. The ChannelClient is a good example of what I want to accomplish in a custom class.

Comment: OK then. See update.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Thank you. Can you take a look at the additions I made? I think the part I am stuck on is how do I call the method and add the listeners at the time I call the method like they do in the ChannelClient example?

Comment: I believe I already covered this in the `addOnSuccessListener` example that returns `this` for chaining.

Comment: Oh! I didn't understand. Ok. Let me try that. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I tried this but I was looking for the call to be message.generate().addOnSuccessListener(new TokenMessage.OnSuccessListener());

Comment: The same concept applies: return `this` in a method you want to chain. See update.

Comment: Perfect! Works great. Thank you.